# Have Yum update vmlinuz, initramfs symlinks in /boot automatically (Fedora)

Tags: boot, fedora, grub, symbolic-link, yum

Whenever Yum updates the kernel, there's a new set of (vmlinuz* initramfs*) files in /boot and the Grub config is updated to directly point to those new files.

**Where is the setting that will force Yum to always create/update symlinks to the new files after such an update?**

> vmlinuz-3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64 # HAVE
>   **vmlinuz -> /boot/vmlinuz-3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64** # WANT
>   initramfs-3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64.img # HAVE
>   **initramfs -> /boot/initramfs-3.12.6-300.fc20.x86_64.img** # WANT

Reasoning:

- A computer with two operating systems installed might have one master Grub with one entry for each system. The Fedora entry would point to symlinks because I'm not manually changing the config file whenever Fedora installs a new kernel.
- In two cases, the Fedora 20 installer failed to install Grub (and crashed). So when this happens, I install a dedicated Grub (not mounted in the Fedora installation) and have the same issue.

Comment: Related [Fedora feature request: Bug 1174465 - Kernel installation: vmlinuz and initramfs.img symlinks should be created/updated](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1174465)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a script in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/` like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

KERNEL_VERSION="$1"
KERNEL_IMAGE="$2"

ln -sf $KERNEL_IMAGE /boot/vmlinuz
ln -sf /boot/initramfs-$KERNEL_VERSION.img /boot/initramfs.img
```

You might also want to put a script in `/etc/kernel/prerm.d/` that handles removing a kernel, which would be more complex. The script would need to work out whether the kernel being removed is symlinked to and work out which kernel to update the symlink to.

The scripts in these directories are called by the `new-kernel-pkg` command, which gets called by `kernel-install` in the post transaction script of a kernel RPM.

Comment: Works like a charm. However, the 2 links have to be changed manually when starting an upgrade with fedup, right before reboot (they have to point to the *-fedup* images). But after the upgrade and after every kernel update, the symlinks are updated properly. Nice.